# Integrate solr search with og group

Tags: organic-groups, search

I search the method to implement apache solr search with og group and search on the content associated with group.

I want that the user can search the content of a specific group or for all group.

Thank

Answer (score 1):

If you want to integrate SOLR with Organic groups,  you can use the [Apache Solr Organic Groups Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_og) module but it is in dev mode.

Also, while searching, you can filter data, and alter queries as required.

Comment: Ok I have installed this module. I have a facet group. But the problem is that I have several type of group and I want to show only one type.

Moreover this type of group is content type I don't want that the user can make a search of this group by type his name in search box.

Comment: If you have already added, you can then go for altering queries on the fly. This is what I did too, and was very much successful. However, if you think in terms of scaling, this would be a bit slower than normal.
Mine is a ~1Lac nodes per groups and counting.
Hopefully, this works for you too.